# Cloudstack KVM installation failed

Tags: kvm, apache-cloudstack

I'm installing cloudstack on ubuntu 20.04 by following [this](https://rohityadav.cloud/blog/cloudstack-kvm/) document.
I installed qemu-kvm and cloudstack-agent successfully but I'm not able to start libvirtd.service, on seeing the status I'm getting following errors

```
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-03-16 18:00:09 IST; 1min 28s ago
TriggeredBy: ● libvirtd-admin.socket
             ● libvirtd.socket
             ● libvirtd-ro.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
             https://libvirt.org
    Process: 232313 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd $libvirtd_opts (code=exited, status=6)
   Main PID: 232313 (code=exited, status=6)

Mar 16 18:00:09 host systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Mar 16 18:00:09 host systemd[1]: Stopped Virtualization daemon.
Mar 16 18:00:09 host systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 16 18:00:09 host systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 16 18:00:09 host systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
```

on seeing the log of `journalctl -xe` it is showing `cloudstack-usage.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'`

can any one suggest what whould be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this on a virtualised VM, or baremetal host, or on a raspberrypi? This means some other service hasn't started which libvirtd may depend on. See if you can run "systemctl daemon-reload" and try to start libvirtd manually "systemctl start libvirtd", and then try rest. The cloudstack-usage service can be started once the mysql server is running. If you've further questions I encourage you to join the CloudStack users mailing list and ask questions there - http://cloudstack.apache.org/mailing-lists.html

Answer (score 0):

I got that same error message when following the official install guide when starting the mysql server. The problem was for me that [mysqld] was missing in the my.conf file before the config snippet. The documentation is misleading in that case (like the secion header is only relevant when editing that alternative mysql config file mentioned later there).